# формане отправляет input

Tags: html, form

В POST  отбражается только sumbit. толи лыжи не едут,толи...

```html
<form id="msform" action="submit.php" method="POST">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
    <li>Adress Details</li>
    <li>Comment</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us about you</h3>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="Your First Name" required="" />
    <input type="text" id="second_name" placeholder="Your Second Name" required="" />
    <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required="" />
    <button type="button" name="next" class="next action-button">NEXT</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Adress Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Enter Your Address</h3>
    <input type="text" id="street" placeholder="Street" required="" />
    <input type="text" id="building" placeholder="Building №" required="" />
    <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="City" required="" />
    <button type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous">PREVIOUS</button>
    <button type="button" name="next" class="next action-button">NEXT</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Comment</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill in your comment</h3>
    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
    <button type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous">PREVIOUS</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button">SUMBIT</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в `input`'ах нет параметра `name`. POST отправляется по `name`, а не по `id`. Например:

```
<input type="text" name="street" id="street" placeholder="Street" required="" />
```